# Watch change in variables

Tags: javascript

I have the following variables in javascript:

```
var stC = {
    kosten: 5,
    tijd: 4,
    locatie: 3,
    beoordeling: 2,
    garantie: 1
};
```

If for example `stC.kosten` changes to 3 I want to change the variable that has the same value, In this example `stC.locatie`, to change to the old value of `stC.kosten`.

So if `stC.kosten` becomes 3 `stC.locatie` becomes 5.
Or if `stC.beoordeling` becomes 5 than `stC.kosten` becomes 2.

Have tried to search, but couldn't found anything to solve the problem.

Does anyone knows how I can do this?

Comment: There's no magic that will do this, you just need to write code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var stC = { kosten: 5, tijd: 4, locatie: 3, beoordeling: 2, garantie: 1 };

function changeValue(obj, key, value){

    var current = obj[key],
        match = getKeyByValue(obj, value);

    if(!match) return;  

    // swap values
    obj[key] = value;
    obj[match] = current;
}

function getKeyByValue(obj, value){
     return Object.keys(obj).filter(function(key) {
         return obj[key] === value; 
     })[0];
}

changeValue(stC, 
           'kosten', // property to change
            3); // new value
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0vsyj603/

If you want to use this pre IE9, use the polyfill for [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Comment: Dont know why you got a downvote - as the only answer that actually provides a working solution, which will work on every browser.

Comment: @Jamiec Seems like someone went on a downvote spree :) And yes, with `Object.keys` shim it will definitely work in all browsers.

Comment: @deruiter2 My pleasure. Please accept the answer if you're happy with it

Comment: my answer is the same, only more robust since your code can sit in any scope, and you are not forced to use the `changeValue`. for example you might need to use it somewhere where it's not accessible. custom events are better in this scenario. you change something, and fire an event and somewhere else in the code it knows about the change and does stuff. perfect.

Comment: @vsync It's up to OP if he wants to use a pub/sub pattern. This answers his question

Comment: I wrote my comment for everyone, not the OP or you. others might come here and read it. it's not about accepting or voting, it's what is best. and if you ever want to scale, you need to build your code ahead, in the smartest way possible, so later you won't waste time dealing with scope issues.

Comment: @vsync I thought a 13k user would know better than to use the term "best". If you want to point out that you prefer a publisher/subscriber pattern, that's fine. Regarding your implementation, I suggest that you make use of jQuery's `$.Callbacks()` rather than involving the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```
stC.prototype = 
{
    setKosten : function(value)
    {
        this.kosten = value;
        this.locatie = whatever;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use object observers.

```
Object.observe(stC, function(changes) {
    changes.forEach(change) {
        switch (change.name) {
             case "kosten":
                 change.object.locatie = change.oldValue;
                 ...
             ...
        }
    });
});
```

Currently you will only find this in Chrome. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe.

Answer (score -2):

You can use getters and setters

```
var o = {
    _kosten: 3,
    get kosten() { return this._kosten; },
    set kosten(x) { this._kosten = x; /* DO YOUR ADDITIONAL LOGIC HERE */ }
};
```

Here is MDN documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set